# Como testar uma alteração em um PR, feita online, localmente?

Tags: git, github

Eu fiz um PR para um repositório no Github, então outros contribuidores do projeto fizeram sugestões nos comentários. Eu usei o próprio Github web para implementar as alterações sugeridas, usando o botão "edit", como ilustrado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ocorre que gostaria de testar localmente minhas alterações. Eu pensei que, após fazer as alterações no Github, eu poderia ter uma versão atualizada no repositório local rodando `git pull origin master`, mas quando fiz isso, recebi a mensagem `local repository already up to date`. Existe uma forma de testar localmente uma alteração feita no PR online *antes* do merge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na documentação tem um passo a passo de como fazer isso, porém depende de possuir o ID do pullrequest:

- https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

Se você usa o GithubCLI pode usar o seguinte comando para listar os pull-requests:

```
gh pr list --repo <dono>/<repositorio>
```

O que facilita, para quem usa Github, obter essas informações. Depois de obter as informações pode usar o

```
git fetch origin pull/<ID>/head:<branch>
```

Trocando `<ID>` e `<branch>` pelos valores obtidos no `gh pr list`